# Entity Framework with SQL Server IGNORE_DUP_KEY

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, duplicates

Is it possible to use SQL Server's `IGNORE_DUP_KEY` with Entity Framerwork's `Add` method?

For example:

```sql
CREATE TABLE A (id int)

CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_DUP] 
ON A ([id] ASC) WITH (IGNORE_DUP_KEY = ON)

INSERT INTO A (id)
VALUES (1), (2), (3)
```

After this, if I do:

```sql
INSERT INTO A (id)
VALUES (2), (4)
```

4 is added, no error is thrown, just an informational message:

> Duplicate key was ignored

If I do

```cs
var db = new DBContext();
db.A.Add(new A { id = 2 };
db.A.Add(new A { id = 5 };

try
{
    db.SaveChanges();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
}
```

No rows are added and I get

> Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded.

I can't find a way around this.

I don't want to make 2 trips to db (check-exists and then insert).

Maybe if I could get `SaveChanges` to append `SET NOCOUNT ON` it would behave the way I'm expecting it to?

Comment: EF will always fail when it detects a difference between affected rows and the number of rows it expects to modify, nothing you can do about that.

Comment: @GertArnold can you not switch this temporarily ? By perhaps disabling concurrency checks ?